# Controller not calling in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am facing problem in call to controller in child ui state router.

URL is changing but controller not call.

no console error*

Please check code:

**HTML**

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"  ui-sref="interactions.details({id:n.id})">Detail</a>
```

**Router**

```
.state('interactions', {
            url: '/interactions',        
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Interaction',
                IsLoginPage: false
            },
            templateUrl: '../../modules/interaction/views/interaction.html',
            controller: 'interactionCtl'
        })
        .state('interactions.details', {
            url:'/details/:id',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Interaction Details',
                IsLoginPage: false
            },
            templateUrl: '../../modules/interaction/views/interactionDetail.html',
            controller:'interactionCtlDetails'
        }).run(function ($rootScope, settings, $cookies, $http, $location, AuthenticationService, $state, $stateParams) {

    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams; 

});
```

**Controller**

```
    warApp.controller('interactionCtlDetails', ["$scope", '$rootScope','$stateParams', 'settings', 'categoryService', 'blockUI',
        function ($scope, interactionService, $rootScope, $stateParams ,settings, categoryService, blockUI) {

            var id = $stateParams.id;
console.log(id);

    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful for others wanting to help to have a working sample of code snippet or jsbin/jsfiddle/codepen sample.

Comment: yeah, this will be helpful. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Annotation array should be in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.Here annotation array is not in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.

Second parameter in your annotation array is 'interactionService' but in function, thats 'rootScope'.

Try with below controller code

```
warApp.controller('interactionCtlDetails', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'settings', 'categoryService', 'blockUI',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams ,settings, categoryService, blockUI) {
        var id = $stateParams.id;
        console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 warApp.controller('interactionCtlDetails', ["$scope", '$rootScope','$stateParams', 'settings', 'categoryService', 'blockUI',
        function ($scope, interactionService, $rootScope, $stateParams ,settings, categoryService, blockUI) {

      var id = $stateParams.id;
       console.log(id);
    });
```

In above code you have `function ($scope, interactionService, $rootScope, $stateParams ,settings, categoryService, blockUI)` where you have `interactionService` which you have missed in  your injection section

Answer (score 0):

Simpler example of routing, maybe you can narrow down the problem by adding one controller at a time and build the rest. Fiddle or error will help.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($stateProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('form', {
        url:"/form",
            views:  {
                "listColumn": { 
                     templateUrl: "/form1.html",
                     controller:'myController1'
                  },
                "formColumn": {
                      templateUrl: "/form2.html"
                  } 
            }
        })  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely your controller should throw an error in console, the order of dependency parameters injected in the controller is wrong, you are missing **`interactionService`**

change it as,

```
warApp.controller('interactionCtlDetails', ["$scope", 'interactionService','$rootScope','$stateParams', 'settings', 'categoryService', 'blockUI',
        function ($scope, interactionService, $rootScope, $stateParams ,settings, categoryService, blockUI) {

    });
```